# Can a Bitcoin Seller steal my Identity?

Tags: identity, banks, identity-theft

I was trying to buy some bitcoins on https://localbitcoins.com.  However, the seller was looking for a copy of my ID and a photo of my debit card (long number covered).

I'm curious as to how open this would leave me to some kind of identity fraud?  Or more specifically could the seller access my bank account?  For information I'm in the UK.

They would have the following details about me:

- Full name
- DOB
- Address
- Licence number
- Copy of photo
- Copy of signature
- Account number
- Sort code
- Bank
- Debit card expiry date

Any info appreciated!

Comment: You could remove the references to Bitcoin and reduce the question to: Could my identity be stolen with this information? And the answer is, of course, yes.

Comment: @schroeder you should post that as a full answer as it addresses OP's question fully

Comment: FWIW, there are may sellers on LBC which do not require so much information. For larger quantities, the most they require is insurance on the package so you can't accuse them of taking the money and pretending it got lost along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Using full name, DoB and signature some banks will allow resetting of login details. Essentially, take the perspective "how accurately can this information prove I am Jon Smith" enough to convince an organisation that you are Jon Smith.

Government issue ID with proof-of-address will generally be enough information to allow for bypassing most authentication systems. Although, without an NI number credit/loans typically cannot be taken out.

However, to answer your initial question, identify fraud is less likely, but a potential issue with the government issue ID and proof-of-address. Furthermore, accessing your bank account is very unlikely, and would require access to mail delivered to your address on file, although this should be confirmed for your own bank.